# Invalid URI format with HttpRequestMessage used by HttpClient

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-web-api, httprequest

In a .NET 6 Web API, in `program.cs` I have this:

The baseAddress content is : https://localhost:7122/ (coming from config file, baseAddress value is ok)

```
builder.Services.AddHttpClient<IMyService, MyService>(client => client.BaseAddress = new Uri(baseAddress));
```

When I execute the code below I get an error "'Invalid URI: The format of the URI could not be determined.' when I create the object `HttpRequestMessage`. I need to send an object when I do `_httpClient.SendAsync`

In `MyService` class

```
public async Task<MyResponse> Search(MyModel myModel)
{
    var httpRequest = new HttpRequestMessage
    {
        Method = HttpMethod.Get,
        RequestUri = new Uri("MyAction/Get"),
        Content =
            new StringContent(
                JsonSerializer.Serialize(myModel),
                Encoding.UTF8,
                MediaTypeNames.Application.Json),
    };

    var response = await _httpClient.SendAsync(httpRequest).ConfigureAwait(false);
    response.EnsureSuccessStatusCode();

    var responseBody = await response.Content
        .ReadFromJsonAsync<MyResponse>()
        .ConfigureAwait(false);

    return responseBody;
}
```

When I replace RequestUri by this : `RequestUri = new Uri($"https://localhost:7122/MyAction/Get")` that's work.

Am I missed something ?

Comment: Why are you using string interpolation for static strings? I suspect that either this isn't the actual code or the configuration values are *not* what you think they are. If such a problem existed every .NET Core developer would have noticed. You'd be able to reproduce it two lines using just `HttpClientHandler` and `HttpClient.GetStringAsync`.

Comment: BTW [HTTP GET isn't supposed to have a body](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7231#page-24). From the HTTP spec : `A payload within a GET request message has no defined semantics;
   sending a payload body on a GET request might cause some existing
   implementations to reject the request.` What does the *actual* code look like?

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos but that's work when I set RequestUri = new Uri($"MyAction/Get")  during  HttpRequestMessage instance. I removed but of course no change. HttpClient.GetStringAsync ok but I need to send an object

Comment: Post *minimal* code that actually reproduces the problem, in the question itself. As for `need to send an object` the only way this would work is if the *server* behaved in a non-standard way. All other servers should *reject* that request. I linked to the RFC standard. That's not a matter of opinion

Comment: No repro with `var client=new HttpClient(){ BaseAddress=new Uri("https://devblogs.microsoft.com/")};
var output=await client.GetStringAsync("visualstudio/datatable-visualizer-improvements/");` Either the URL isn't what you think, or `_httpClient` isn't the HttpClient instance injected by DI.